# the definition of relative Thom spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

I find the definition of Thom space on the book Characteristic classes, J.W. Milnor, J.D. Stasheff, page 205:

For   a vector bundle $\xi$ with a Riemannian metric  over a $CW$-complex $B$,  let $A$ be the subset of the total space $E(\xi)$ consisting of all vectors $v$ with $|v|\geq 1$.  Then the space $E(\xi)/A$ in which $A$ is pinched to a point is called the    **Thom space**  of $\xi$, denoted by $T(\xi)$.

**Question.** Let $B_0$ be a $CW$-subcomplex of $B$ and $\xi_0$ the restriction of $\xi$ on $B_0$. Are there any **references** for the definition of the **relative Thom space** of the pair $(\xi,\xi_0)$?

Comment: Where have you seen the term? Assuming the source didn't define it did you check any of the references given there?